# Passing collection to JPA repository error

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have 3 classes that I want to interact by JPA Repository:

1. *Goal* - dictionary for user's goals. Connected with *"Unit"* class as Many(goal) to One (Unit). So every Goal can be linked with just one *Unit*.
2. *Role* - holds user's rights in the System. Connected with *Unit* class the same way as *Goal*. So every Role can have only one Unit too.
3. *Unit* - holds subdivision. Used as dictionary by the two classes above.

*Goal* entity is backed by *GoalReposotory* and  *GoalServiceImpl*, which is my main interface for CRUD.

**The issue:** I want to pass a collection of *Role*’s objects to repository (*GoalServiceImpl*) to get a set of "Goals", which has the same *Unit*s as the set of *Role*s. So I can filter list of Goals by just passing a Role parameter.

I add this to my CrudRepostitory 
`Iterable<Goal> getGoalsByUnits (List<Unit> unit);` 
and getting an error:

```
 “Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.lang.Iterable com.platform.repository.GoalRepository.getGoalsByUnits(java.util.Set)! No property units found for type Goal! Did you mean 'unit'?”
```

What I'm doing wrong? Mybe it's because I have only one *Unit* for every *Goal* object?
What are the best way for solving my task?

**Goal Class**

```
public class Goal {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
   private Long id;

   @Column(name = "DESCR", length = 255, nullable = false)
   public String descr;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn (name="UNIT_ID", nullable = false)
   public Unit unit; //UNIT IS HERE!

   @Column(name = "VL")
   private float vl;
```

**Unit class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="UNITS", schema="MAPP")
public class Unit {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "UNITNAME")
    private String unitname;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "unit")
    Set<Role> role;
```

**Role class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ROLES", schema="MAPP")
public class Role implements GrantedAuthority {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "ROLENAME")
    private String rolename;

    @Column(name = "FULLNAME")
    private String fullname;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "UNIT_ID")
    private Unit unit;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PERMISSION_ID")
    private Permission permission;
```

**Goal Repository**

```
public interface GoalRepository extends CrudRepository<Goal, Long> {

    Iterable<Goal> getGoalsByUnit (Unit unit);
    Iterable<Goal> getGoalsByUnits (List<Unit> unit);
}
```

**Goal Repository interface**

```
public class GoalServiceImpl implements GoalService {

public Iterable<Goal> getByRoles (Set<Role> roles) {
    List<Unit> units = new ArrayList<>();
    roles.forEach(e -> {
            units.add(e.getUnit());
    });
    return rep.getGoalsByUnits(units);
}
```

Comment: Did you try `getGoalsByUnitIn(List<Unit> unit)`?

Comment: Thank you! It works.

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help you. I posted the answer if you want to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sprint Data JPA provides numerous [naming conventions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation) for repository methods that help us define the way we want to fetch data from DB without the need to write queries.

In your case, you wanted to use `in` clause which cannot be achieved with plural so your method needs to be named `getGoalsByUnitIn`.